# Vraptor (Metodo com conexão URL)

Tags: java, vraptor

Boa tarde, estou tentando executar um código no Vraptor, que ao executar minha rota, preciso que o sistema dispare uma conexão utilizando URL para uma pagina e retorne o corpo.

Este é um metodo do meu controller

```
public void exe(){
        try{
            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com.br");
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        result.redirectTo(HomeController.class).index();
        return;
    }
```

Coloquei aqui um exemplo só de testes, e o seguinte erro é retornado:

```
WELD-001435: Normal scoped bean class br.com.teste.controllers.ModuloController is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor - <unknown javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean instance>.
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Parece um erro do CDI, por acaso você tem um construtor vazio no controller?

Comment: Realmente eu não tinha me atentado que a classe não possuía o construtor vazio. vlw